# Need to re-record part of OpenScript script but don't want to re-record the whole script

Tags: oracle, openscript

We would like to fix a portion of a script in OpenScript by re-recording the part that's not working in lieu of re-recording the whole script.  We can't seem to figure out how to do it.  Every time we try, Open Script starts with the log in to the testing program.  It seems you should be able to start recording at any point.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

create a test script, click on **Record**, once it launches, in Openscript toolbar **pause** the recording. Now the recording is stopped, whatever we do will not be recorded .Manually perform the sections which you don't want to record. Then **click on resume** on the openscript toolbar. Now it will be recorded.

Once done, copy the generated code to the actual script.

[If you are using object library add this as an asset in actual script]

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Recording from opened browser is supported in Oracle Application testing suite .

```
1. Open OATS Tool
2. Launch IE
3. navigate to UI where you want to start recording
4. There is Globe icon top (menu Icons), select opened browser
5. Select record
6. Steps will be recorded in Editor
```

Image:
[image]

For more OATS related tips, visit here www.testinghive.com